# Du très bon fromage ou un très bon fromage

Tags: grammaire, articles, partitif

As far as I know the first one is correct but lately I was doing some exercises and the answer written in the model answer was (un très bon fromage).

Comment: Also as a side remark be careful with the French diacritics (a headache sometimes:-)!). It is très and not trés. Mozilla, Google Chrome spell checkers can detect such typos. As a secondary remark it is I (capital letter) the first person personal pronoun in English (on the contrary in French there is not such capitalisation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful to write down the particular exercice.

From an ad:

> Du très bon fromage (cheese in its general meaning)... Très bonne
>   fromagerie qui vend ce qu'elle produit. C'est de la qualité et les
>   prix sont très corrects.
>
> (...)
>
> Le camembert (un fromage à pâte molle fabriqué principalement en
>   Normandie) est un très bon fromage.

In addition keep in mind that:

> Un bon fromage : Une situation avantageuse. (expression imagée)

https://www.cordial.fr/dictionnaire/definition/fromage.php

Comment: The exercise : Traduire les phrases suivantes: •I chose a very good cheese. (Model answer: J’ai choisi un très bon fromage)                   from book " complete french grammer,practice makes perfect"                                         And really thanks for answering i thought it was impossible to use (un) with fromage i think i should restudy in deeper detail the indefinite articles

Comment: Basically "Du fromage" is about the matter, while "Un fromage" is about a specifc brand or receipt. Note also that I never ever heard "Un bon fromage" used as an expression meaning "Une situation avantageuse" as stated in this answer

Comment: @LaurentS. Thanks for the comment but see also here for verification https://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-definition/un+bon+fromage and here [Au fig., fam. Situation lucrative et de tout repos. Synon. sinécure.Il a trouvé un fromage, un bon fromage; se retirer dans un fromage (Ac.1932) : ] http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/fromage and here http://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/definition/un_bon_fromage.php . See also the reference in my response.

Comment: I can totally admit it exists and is correct, but being barely 40 years I never encountered it myself (Belgium) and wouldn't have understood it before I got this explanation...

Comment: @LaurentS. Pas de problèmes. Comme vous connaissez mieux que moi la langue française possède une pléthore d'expressions imagées:-)!